# pyinstaller ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Tags: python, setuptools, pyinstaller

I am trying to package up my Python script using Pyinstaller.  My script imports the third party modules Exscript and Netaddr.  I get the error below when I try to run the executable generated by Pyinstaller.

I know "pkg_resources" refers to setuptools, but I checked and I have setuptools 18.2 under site-packages and I see easy install in the scripts directory.  I'm running Python 2.7.

Any help with getting Pyinstaller to work is appreciated. FYI, I did search and review similar questions here and they did not apply to this particular problem.

**Here is the output from running Pyinstaller(I only included the errors):**

```
C:\Python27\Lib\PyInstaller-2.1>pyinstaller c:\users\<username>\pycharmprojects\neworking2\network_login.py
5759 INFO: building because out00-Tree.toc missing or bad
5983 INFO: building because out01-Tree.toc missing or bad
7097 INFO: rebuilding out00-PYZ.toc because out00-PYZ.pyz is missing
9569 INFO: rebuilding out00-PKG.toc because out00-PKG.pkg is missing
9591 INFO: rebuilding out00-EXE.toc because network_login.exe missing
```

**The output of executing the .exe generated by Pyinstaller:**

```
 C:\Python27\Lib\PyInstaller-2.1\network_login\dist\network_login>network_loginTraceback (most recent call last):
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\transport.py", line 49, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\dsskey.py", line 26, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py", line 89, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Crypto\Random\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py", line 28, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\winrandom.py", line 7, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\winrandom.py", line 3, in __bootstrap__ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Answer (score 3):

Just import it as:

```
import pkg_resources.py2_warn
```

In the main file.

Answer (score 1):

When my script import a module apscheduler, I met a similar error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    File "d:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\schedulers\base.py", line 9, in <module>
      from pkg_resources import iter_entry_points
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
scheduler2 returned -1
```

It seems that pyinstaller can not extract the content from setuptools*.egg that you installed.

**My workaround is to manually extract setuptools*.egg from python lib directory (PYTHON_INSTALL_PATH\lib\site-packages\setuptools*.egg) to the same directory of the problem script, and run pyinstaller again.**

In my environment, copy D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py2.7.egg to the same directory of my py script, rename it to setuptools-18.4-py2.7.zip, and extract the content (don't create new direcotry setuptools-18.4-py2.7) to the same dir of my py script.

Comment: I just [pushed a fix](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/commit/a6f4ba484f21b31620215f32451293c6964699ac) for this bug to [PyInstaller's github](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller). It wasn't detecting .py files inside of .eggs correctly.

Comment: I got a similar error in Unity engine during a WebGL build and your answer helped me find out where I was supposed to have pkg_resources but did not. Turns out pip was not installed at all for Python2 (I'm only developing with Python3), so I just installed it (and yeah we should not rely on Python2 anymore in 2020 but there's still a good legacy of tools using it)